# Most efficient way of showing or calling repeat/duplicate HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have five div elements containing the same six images. Only one div is shown at a time (others are display:none) but all are on the same page. Basic example:

```
<div class="one">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
</div>
<div class="one">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
    <img src="hello.png" class="wave">
</div>
```

Is there a more efficient way of showing these duplicate sets? Perhaps an array or innerHTML.

Comment: A loop? `for` should be fine?

Comment: In most cases your HTML gets generated. However we don't know enough about the way you retrieve this HTML. You should also look into JS template engines such as Handlebars. https://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://jsfiddle.net/sumit_sharmaXD/xL4rqbg2/6/

Comment: If your HTML is *already* generated, as implied by "*others are display:none*" then showing them is just `$(".on").show()` - but you ask if there's a *more efficient way of showing* - more efficient than what?

Comment: @freedomn-m  _more efficient way of showing these **duplicate** sets_. Perhaps I meant coding these sets or minifying the HTML so as to not have the same repeating line 30 times.

Comment: Ah, *generating* the HTML - "showing" implies ".show()" or `display:block` especially as you already mention that "others are display:none"

Comment: Would need to know your requirements / how it's generated in the first place.  If it's *exactly* the same and you just don't want a 300 line HTML file, then you could have one and use [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and/or you could use a [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element, or you could build the whole lot using js (the html in the js).   If they're not exactly the same, then it will need to be data-driven (eg an array), but there's no point in having an array with 5 elements identical.

Comment: Depending on what it's for, there may be an alternative solution, such as a background image on repeat: [background-repeat (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)